# Powershell NAS command not working

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get NAS drive parameters using PS commands.  The below command, however, is not getting any value when called via Python code by connecting to remote server. However, if I run it by copy-pasting into that remote server it gives output.

```
$nas = Get-PSDrive | Where-Object {$_.DisplayRoot -like '*jkl.com*'}
write-host $nas
```

No error and no output when run through Python code.

Comment: So how do you call it via Python? Show us that code, too.

Comment: By using winrm, this code has no issues as its been used for many commands and it has no issues at all